# Using Multi Spec and R for batch Image Analysis

Tags: r, batch-processing, imaging

Is it possible to use R to enable a batch of images to be run through Multi Spec (or any other program - excluding ImageJ) instead of single image analysis?

And if so how?

I've attached images of exactly what I am looking for using the following links:
"http://figshare.com/s/f81b92ea474f11e5b78d06ec4bbcf141"
"http://figshare.com/s/463ec4ce475011e5909106ec4b8d1f61"

The "Edit" image is a copy of "ms485_a7c5,c3aR 40x gm 1.tif" with highlighted boxes of what I'm searching for.

The black boxes surrounding the blue circles are one set of data that I'm looking for, specifically the number of them in the image as well the % area of the image that they cover. 
The red boxes surrounding the merged blue and brown areas are also something I'm specifically looking for with the same values needed as above.
Finally the brown areas of the image are also what I'm looking for, but only for the % area covered in the image.

I'm able to carry out the analysis of 1 image on Multi-Spec but I need this to be carried on 1000+ images and am unable to do this as I'm unfamiliar with R or other coding programmes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't assuming that you can do what you need to from the command line. But using R solely as a batch processing tool is probably more trouble than its worth.  What kind of image processing task are you trying to solve?  I think you need to be more explicit in the process otherwise you won't get any specific suggestions for alternatives or good approaches.

Comment: I'm looking at cell imaging rather than satellite imaging but it has the same principles. I have over 1000 images with the same 4 colours (brown, blue,white, and brown overlapping blue) and I am trying to look at the surface area that these cells cover. 
I've found that Multi Spec has far better advantages to what I'm looking for compared to ImageJ as I would like to use the same wavelength of colour in each new image.
If there is any more information required then please comment.

Thanks

Comment: How large are these images and in what format are they? Are the "colors" fixed/classified or are you dealing with RGB images?  What I'm trying to get at is whether you need an outside tool or whether you can use the `raster` package directly...

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens The images are roughly 15MB and the dimensions are 2600x2060 pixels. The colours are also fixed. Is there a way to upload the image and the properties (colours) I'm interested in onto here? Thanks

Comment: You could add them to figshare or link them from Dropbox, etc.  But your best bet would be simulate data that's similar.  It sounds like what you want could be accomplished in a few lines of code in R itself.  You essentially just want a count of pixels by color?

Comment: Thanks I've added a few images to figshare (http://figshare.com/account/my_data#session=92887399) to give you an idea of what I'm looking for. 
The "Edit" image is a copy of "ms485_a7c5,c3aR 40x gm 1.tif" with highlighted boxes of what I'm searching for.
The black boxes surrounding the blue circles are one set of data that I'm looking for, specifically the number of them in the image as well the % area of the image that they cover.
The red boxes surrounding the merged blue and brown areas are also something I'm specifically looking for with the same values needed as above.

Comment: Finally the brown areas of the image are also what I'm looking for, but only for the % area covered in the image. I'm able to carry out the analysis of 1 image on Multi-Spec but I need this to be carried on 1000+ images and am unable to do this as I'm unfamiliar with R or other coding programmes. To answer your question a count of pixels by colour is essentially the % area covered so that would be extremely helpful. If the link doesn't work or any more information is needed please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks @ForrestR.Stevens

Comment: The link doesn't work, you should find the link that goes directly to your posted resource, not  your session link.  Also, you should add these details and edit your original question so people working on similar problems can find your question easily through StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @ForrestR.Stevens. The links are now in the question area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know how far this will get you, but processing each image one at a time should be do-able within your memory limits.  The approach outlined is the most basic of thresholding applied to your images.  Much more sophisticated approaches could be applied:

```
library(raster)

i <- brick("./data/ms485_a7c5_c3aR_40x_gm_1.tif")
names(i) <- c("r", "g", "b")

##  Plot image:
plotRGB(i)
```

[image]

```
##  Here you could use a more sophisticated classification method:
#k <- kmeans(i[], centers=4, iter.max = 100, nstart = 4)
#c <- raster(i)
#c[] <- c$cluster

##  Instead we'll just set some simple thresholds:
c1 <- (i$r < 170 & i$g < 140 & i$b > 150)*1  ## Blues
c2 <- (i$r > 150 & i$g > 150 & i$b > 150)*2  ## Lights
c3 <- (i$r < 170 & i$g < 150 & i$b < 140)*3  ## Darks

##  Plot the classified data so you see what you're summarizing below:
plot(c, add=T, legend=F, col=c(
  rgb(255, 255, 255, maxColorValue=255),
  rgb(100, 100, 180, maxColorValue=255),
  rgb(220, 220, 220, maxColorValue=255),
  rgb(120, 100, 90, maxColorValue=255)
))
```

[image]

```
##  And calculate your summary stats by class:

t <- table(c[])
names(t) <- c("Unclassified", "Blues", "Lights", "Darks")
t

##  Unclassified        Blues       Lights        Darks 
##        283887       220042      4475129       376942

##  Or we can calculate those cell counts as percentages of pixels:
t/ncell(c) * 100

##  Unclassified        Blues       Lights        Darks 
##      5.300355     4.108327    83.553566     7.037752
```

Now, because you have not already segmented or thresholded your images using a technique that can accurately identify your blue areas, you're going to have to figure out the best approach that works for you.  Once you have a classified image you could use the `SDMTools` package to calculate the number of distinct patches, etc. that occur within your images.

```
##  To summarize distinct patches within your classified "Blues":
library(SDMTools)

##  Calculate stats, and count all patches for "Blues":
class_stats <- ClassStat(c1, cellsize=1, bkgd=0)
class_stats$n.patches

##  [1] 1858

##  Only count patches larger than 10 pixels:
image_clusters <- ConnCompLabel( c1 )
patch_stats <- PatchStat(image_clusters, cellsize=1)
sum(patch_stats[patch_stats$patchID>0,]$n.cell > 10)

##  [1] 462
```